# как получить id связного обьекта в django, jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja

Пишу сайт для обучения с тестами и лекциями, зашёл в тупик когда пытался получить id объекта `Question` для передачи в url.

связь выглядит следующим образом

> lesson ← lection ← question ← choice

хочу в шаблоне lesson.html получить question.id из lection, попробовал `{%for q in lec.question_set.all%}` но ничего не выводит

в чём ошибка ?
есть ли решение проблемы ?

**model.py**

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subjects = models.CharField(max_length=23)
    
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return (self.pk)

class Lection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lecter = models.FileField(upload_to='lecters/%y/%m/%d/',max_length=200)
    les = models.ForeignKey(Lesson,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True ,blank=True)


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_created=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.pk



    @admin.display(
        boolean=True,
        ordering='pub_date',
        description='Published recently ?',
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bal = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

**views.py**

```
def ViewLesson(request,lesson_id):
    lesson = Lesson.objects.filter(pk=lesson_id)
    return render(request,'polls/lesson.html',{'lesson':lesson)
```

**lesson.html**

```html
{%extends  'base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{%block content%}


    {%if lesson %}

        <p>{{lesson.subjects}}</p>

        {%for l in lesson%}
            <ul>
              <li>{{ l.title }}</li>
              <li>{{l.subjects}}</li>
            </ul>


            {%for lec in l.lection_set.all%}
                <ul>
                  <li>{{lec.title}}</li>
                  {%if lec.question%}

                      {%for q in lec.question_set.all%}
                        <li><a href="">{{q.question_text}}</a></li>
                      {%endfor%}

                  {%endif%}

                </ul>
            {%endfor%}
        {%endfor%}

    {%else%}
        <h1>isn't working</h1>
    {%endif%}

{%endblock%}
```

Comment: у вас нет связи модели Question к Lection

Comment: Ну у вас связи построены так, что у одной лекции - один вопрос. А у одного вопроса - много лекций. В общем неправильно построены

Comment: Это не jinja. .

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь, учёл ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Александру, объяснил ошибку при создании связей между моделями. Был неправильно составлен ForeingKey.

В моём случае модель Lection наследовалось к модели Question, из за чего у многих лекций был 1 вопрос, что было неверно.

На будущее определил что при проектировке ForeingKey его нужно указывать к модели которая будет множеством другой модели.

**model.py**

```
class Lection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lecter = models.FileField(upload_to='lecters/%y/%m/%d/',max_length=200)
    les = models.ForeignKey(Lesson,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    null=True ,blank=True)


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_created=True)
    **lec = models.ForeingKey(Lection,null=True,on_delete=model.CASCADE) # теперь у 1 лекции будет много вопросов**

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.pk



    @admin.display(
        boolean=True,
        ordering='pub_date',
        description='Published recently ?',
```

Comment: Этот ответ можно улучшить, его можно отредактировать. Добавьте деталей, что именно вы сделали, чтобы решить проблему. Эта информация может кому-то в будущем оказаться полезной.